# search array of dictionaries and extract value

Tags: python, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got the following data:

```
[{'name': 'SqueezePlay', 'power': '1', 'playerid': '91:e2:b5:24:49:63', 'ip': '192.168.1.144:51346', 'canpoweroff': 1, 'displaytype': 'none', 'seq_no': '10', 'connected': 1, 'isplayer': 1, 'model': 'squeezeplay', 'uuid': 'fgh79fg7h98789798978'}, {'name': "FLX's iPhone", 'power': '1', 'playerid': '4c:32:d1:45:6c:4e', 'ip': '84.105.161.205:53972', 'canpoweroff': 1, 'displaytype': 'none', 'seq_no': 0, 'connected': 1, 'isplayer': 1, 'model': 'iPengiPod', 'uuid': '9791c009e3e7fghfg346456456'}]
```

I changed the values for privacy means.
I'd like to search the array based on "name" ("SqueezePlay" for example) and I'd to retrieve the "playerid" ("91:e2:b5:24:49:63" for example).

What would be the most efficient way to do this in Python? Thanks!

Comment: It's not an array.  Can you fix the question to call it a "dictionary", since that's what it really is.

Comment: It's an array of dictionaries, technically.

Comment: A List of dictionaries, if we want to be fussy. But this isn't the goal of question.

Comment: Are the `name`s guaranteed to be unique?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your list of dicts is `data`, then you can try this:

```
next(d for d in data if d['name'] == 'SqueezePlay')['playerid']
```

This returns `'91:e2:b5:24:49:63'` (for the first occurence of the given name).

You have to define what to do if given `name` is not in your `data`.

Answer (score 1):

Define a function to find a player based on its name:

```
def find_player(all_players, name):
    for player in all_players:
        if player['name'] == name:
            return player['playerid']
```

This way (I'm guessing `name` is unique) you don't have to loop the whole list of players, instead, once you find it, return its `playerid`:

```
>>> p = [{'name': 'SqueezePlay', 'power': '1', 'playerid': '91:e2:b5:24:49:63', 'ip': '192.168.1.144:51346', 'canpoweroff': 1, 'displaytype': 'none', 'seq_no': '10', 'connected': 1, 'isplayer': 1, 'model': 'squeezeplay', 'uuid': 'fgh79fg7h98789798978'}, {'name': "FLX's iPhone", 'power': '1', 'playerid': '4c:32:d1:45:6c:4e', 'ip': '84.105.161.205:53972', 'canpoweroff': 1, 'displaytype': 'none', 'seq_no': 0, 'connected': 1, 'isplayer': 1, 'model': 'iPengiPod', 'uuid': '9791c009e3e7fghfg346456456'}]
>>> find_player(p, 'SqueezePlay')
'91:e2:b5:24:49:63'
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions posted by others work great if you are only searching the list once or a few times. If you will be searching it frequently, or if the list is more than a few items, and the names are guaranteed to be unique, it might pay off to make a dictionary from that list once, and then access the items by name in that dictionary. Or, if your program is making the list, put them in a dictionary to begin with. (If the order is important, i.e. you want to display the items in the order they were entered by a user, use a `collections.OrderedDict`.)

```
lyst = [{'name': 'SqueezePlay', 'power': '1', 'playerid': '91:e2:b5:24:49:63', 
         'ip': '192.168.1.144:51346', 'canpoweroff': 1, 'displaytype': 'none',
         'seq_no': '10', 'connected': 1, 'isplayer': 1, 'model': 'squeezeplay',
         'uuid': 'fgh79fg7h98789798978'}, {'name': "FLX's iPhone", 'power': '1',
         'playerid': '4c:32:d1:45:6c:4e', 'ip': '84.105.161.205:53972',
         'canpoweroff': 1, 'displaytype': 'none', 'seq_no': 0, 'connected': 1,
         'isplayer': 1, 'model': 'iPengiPod', 'uuid': '9791c009e3e7fghfg346456456'}]

dyct = dict((item.pop("name"), item) for item in lyst)
# Python 3: {item.pop("name"): item for item in lyst}

print dyct["SqueezePlay"]
```

Note that the resulting dictionary no longer has `name` as a key of the nested dictionaries; it has been popped to avoid duplicating data in two places (if you keep it in two places, it's twice as much work to update it, and if you forget somewhere, they get out of sync). If you want to keep it, write this instead:

```
dyct = dict((item["name"], item) for item in lyst)
# Python 3: {item["name"]: item for item in lyst}
```